# use dynamic ngrx selector or ngrx action for better performance?

Tags: angular, redux, store, ngrx

I would get data from store depending on a parameter

I have created the selector but with static parameter

```
export const selectSchedulingsTimes = createSelector(
  schedulings,
  (state: ISchedulesState, { time }: { time: string }) => {
    let nowFormat = moment(time, 'HH:mm');
    return state.schedulings.data.filter(elm => {
      let before = moment(elm.tp_org_r, 'HH:mm:ss');
      let after = moment(elm.tp_des_r, 'HH:mm:ss');

      let checkifBetween = nowFormat.isBetween(before, after);

      if (checkifBetween) {
        return elm;
      }
    });
  }
);
```

then passing parameter in my component

```
export class LineSynopticComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  schedules$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectSchedulingsTimes, { time: '10:34' }));

ngOninit(){
}
```

as `schedules$` is not declared inside ngOnOnit if I set a variable instead of `10:34` will it be working ?

Is it better to use a reducer the send back the values or selector are more performant ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem calling a selector with a parameter. Just make sure the parameter exist when you call your selector. I would do something like this:

- Declare your observable.
- Call the selector where your parameters is going to be available, I used onInit since this is the only thing you provided.

  ```
  schedules$: Observable<any> // whatever type it should be returning

  ngOninit(){
     this.schedules$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectSchedulingsTimes, { time: '10:34' }));
  }
  ```

Comment: Your Answer respond to my problem but I have another one now. here's the question link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57267134/ngrx-selector-with-dynamic-parameter-not-triggered