# Piping inside a subscribe in ngrx

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, store, ngrx

I have a selector that takes a parameter to filter values.

The parameter depends on an observable's return.

```
export class LineSynopticComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

schedules$: Observable<ISchedule[]>;

ngOninit(){
  this.selectedDate$.subscribe(elm => {
  this.schedules$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectSchedulingsTimes, { time: elm.timeSelect }));
});
}
```

the `selectSchedulingsTimes` selector is defined as well:

```
const schedulings = (state: IAppState) => state.schedulings;

export const selectSchedulingsTimes = createSelector(
  schedulings,
  (state: ISchedulesState, { time }: { time: string }) => {
    let nowFormat = moment(time, 'HH:mm');
    return state.schedulings.data.filter(elm => {
      ... 
      return elm
    });
  }
);
```

in a second time I subscribe to `schedules$`

```
this.schedules$.subscribe((schedules: ISchedule[]) => {

  ...

}
```

I get inside `selectSchedulingsTimes` selector only once when application is started, but when I change values of `selectedDate$` the selector is not triggered so I'm not entering in `selectSchedulingsTimes`.

How can I make selector send new data every change on `selectedDate`?

Is it because I'm not subscribing to `schedules$` ?

Don't hesitate to ask me for unclear parts

Comment: Does it get inside the subscribe more than once

Comment: 2 times when on init app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's change your observable setup like this:

```
ngOninit(){

    this.selectedData$.pipe(
      switchMap((elm) => {
        return this.store.pipe(select(selectSchedulingsTimes, { time: elm.timeSelect }));
      })
    ).subscribe((resposeFromStore) => {
      //Do whatever you want tot do with the store value
      console.log(resposeFromStore);      
    })    
  }
```

You need not subscribe on `selectedData$` and then set up your other observable.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your selector is the problem. You should read [this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/ngrx-parameterized-selector-e3f610529f8), its giving some good example and it also contains a section regarding dynamic parameters. Thats what I would try:

```
export const selectSchedulingsTimes = createSelector(
  schedulings,
  schedule => (time: string) => {
    let nowFormat = moment(time, 'HH:mm');
    return state.schedulings.data.filter(elm => {
      ... 
      return elm
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: What is schedule ? is it state ?

Comment: yes, its just a name, you can use whatever you want